# How to POST a JSON with data provided by user with REACTJS and Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios

I've tried to do this multiple ways but when I try to submit the json with info edited by the user I do get the 200 OK response however the JSON isn't uploaded in the correct format.
The JSON I'm trying to upload, I want "codigo_pedido_integracao" to be provided by the user:

```
        this.state = {
            cabecalho: {
              codigo_cenario_impostos: '1594402482',
              codigo_cliente: 1595284133,
              codigo_pedido_integracao: '1234',
              codigo_parcela: '000',
              data_previsao: '',
              etapa: 10
            }}
```

My code line with the user info request:

```
    render(){
        const {codigo_pedido_integracao} = this.state
        return(
            <div>  
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>  
                <label>
                    Codigo pedido:
            <div>
                <input type ="codigo_pedido_integracao" name="codigo_pedido_integracao" value= {codigo_pedido_integracao} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
            </div>   
            </label>  
         <button type = "submit">Enviar</button>
         </form>
      </div>

        )

    }
}
```

This is the object sent to the API:

```
cabecalho:
codigo_cenario_impostos: "1594402482"
codigo_cliente: 1595284133
codigo_parcela: "000"
codigo_pedido_integracao: "1234"
data_previsao: ""
etapa: 10
__proto__: Object
codigo_pedido_integracao: "999999"
```

My intention was that "codigo_pedido_integrcao" was provided by the user and not upload with the "1234" standard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the state to the input value in its change handler. Something like -

```
    changeHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            codigo_pedido_integracao: e.target.value
        })
    }
```

Comment: when I do that, I still get the same issue, codigo_pedido_integracao is uploaded as the standard 1234 and not with the info provided by the user, which is uploaded after the "__proto__": Object

Comment: You need to provide whole component code. Need to see how you are sending data from Axios. From your code it appears that you are quite new to React.